Can figere come with a dative?
Several times encountered the verb figo with what I understood to be a dative (like this example from L&S: foribus miser oscula figit (Lucretius).)
But now upon scanning L&S, it seems to say this is not a dative but a poetical bare ablative? Is that so? It would make a difference when the thing we fix something to is of first declination.

The answer to the titular question is: yes, it can.
It cannot be ruled out that Lucretii foribus miser oscula figit is an ablative (though I would be disinclined to follow this reading, see below), but it certainly is a dative when Ovid writes (about Cadmus, when his special cow lies down, indicating the place where to build Thebes; Metamorphoses 3, 24):

Cadmus agit grates peregrinaeque oscula terrae figit et ignotos montes agrosque salutat.

(Except if you want to read this as a locative …)
I also think this is a little different from the Fasti example you cite in your answer. Solida humo ramos figere means, if I understand correctly, to drive sticks into the earth in preparation for some kind of bonfire. The solid earth is really more of a place than a recipient or even beneficiary here. The same does not apply to the expression osculos figere, clearly.

Thanks. So guess it was dative after all :). I get what you are saying but still the distinction between the ablative to a dative is somewhat blurred.

Upon further research, it is probably an ablative. and using a dative with figo is likely impossible. At the very least, the reading of foribus as a bare ablative is possible. It is shown by this example:

et solidā ramos figere pugnat humo (Ovid, Fasti). [Note the poetical usage of "pugno + inf."]

It might be the case that I got swayed by the prefixed versions of the verb (just like many other prefixed verbs), which allows a dative: portaeque infigitur hasta (Verg.A.9.746)

Prefixed verbs seem to like datives more than bare ones in general, at least in my experience. I couldn't find an earlier question on this correlation, though.

@JoonasIlmavirta, I learnt this tip about prefix verbs and datives on this site. I think Mitomino mentioned this several times, here is one example. But it was dealt with in context of something else.
